# 0% usage of integrated GPU when playing videos on chrome?

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, gpu

Sorry this might be a bad question, but why isn't the iGPU being used at all for playing video? Shouldn't it be used at least a little for encoding/decoding video? I have hardware acceleration and everything seems to be enabled on chrome:

[image: chrome://gpu]

Here is a test of youtube running on chrome, with gpu showing 0% on stats.app and activity monitor.

[image: youtube test]

Chrome dev tools > Media shows video encoder and decoder are not available(?). So is everything being software encoded/decoded, which explains the higher CPU usage?
[image: chrome dev tools]

My specs:

- MacBook Pro 2015 13 inch
- Intel Core i7-5557U 3.10GHz
- Intel Iris Graphics 6100
- 16GB DDR3

Would greatly appreciate an explanation for this. Thank you!

Comment: Sure seems like Chrome is only using CPU. That would explain why it's such a CPU (and RAM) resource hog, to say nothing of the security problems.

Comment: I see.. GPU is definitely being used to render pages. There just seems to be low usage across all web browsers when playing video. Would this have something to do with it: https://superuser.com/a/1036307?

Comment: Yes, I was going to add that it could depend on the codec.